# Selenium webdriver : how to find the element in DOM based on custom attribute

Tags: selenium

How can I find the element in DOM based on a custom attribute?

For example:

DOM attributes are not present in HTML view. Using DOM inspector I can able to identified the Custom attribute is unique.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("SimpleSearch:dIndicesGrid:1:Value")).getAttribute("_celltype");
```

Here `_celltype` is custom attribute. This attribute is not visible in HTML view.

Answer (score 24):

XPath is evil, you could use this instead

```
By.CssSelector("[_celltype='celltype']");
```

Comment: CssSelector is preferable. Reads easier too.

Comment: It is also faster. I am running an application in which XPath is basically 6 times slower than any other selector. Since I have to run this operation multiple times, it makes a huge difference in the total running time for my app.

Answer (score 19):

You would have to locate the element by xpath.

The following would find any element that has the _celltype attribute with value 'celltype':

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@_celltype='celltype']"))
```

If you know what type of element it is you can make it more specific. For example, if you know they are div tags, do:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@_celltype='celltype']"))
```

Comment: but i need get the value from _celltype.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand your goal. Are you trying to find an element based on its _celltype attribute or are you trying to find the _celltype attribute value of an element? To me it looks like the former is covered by this answer and the latter by the code in your question. Could you clarify what you are looking for, perhaps give a sample HTML and what value/element you are trying to get from it?

Comment: sorry i was try to ask the how to read the Custom DOM attribute(_celltype)  of the web element.

Comment: Okay, so you are saying the code you have in your question does not work? What is the exception and the HTML of the page?

Comment: There is no exception, simply it returns empty string. Since it cant able to read the custom attribute which wrote by javascript after render the response. HTML also not help. Since response content doesnt have those attribute. After response loaded, some javascript component wrote this attribute on the TD cell object.

Answer (score 2):

Find the element by xPath:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_link"));

xpath_link = //*[@_celltype='celltype']; // This is sample xpath;

System.out.println(element.getText());
```

This will get the text of 'celltype' field and displays the value of it.