# Besides Xpath, how do I capture custom attributes

Tags: ruby, selenium, attributes

I'm trying to capture the date of an object but the object does not have id or name attributes.  Also there are multiple items with the class of "ng-binding" so I don't think I can use that.

Is there a way for me to capture values from objects using custom attributes?  Meaning is there a way for me in Ruby to say
      varObject = find_element(:ng-binding-html, "$ctrl.app.publishedDate")

The object I'm trying to capture is

```
  <span ng-bind-html="$ctrl.app.publishedDate" class="ng-binding">11/20/2017</span>
```

I took a look at an older post which seems to be close to the same issue I'm having but I was sure.

[Selenium webdriver : how to find the element in DOM based on custom attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723422/selenium-webdriver-how-to-find-the-element-in-dom-based-on-custom-attribute)

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you don't want to use XPath? The Ruby Selenium WebDriver find_element method that I think you refer to in your question accepts XPaths as an argument.

You could use the following XPath:

```
"//span[@ng-bind-html='$ctrl.app.publishedDate']"
```

Your Ruby code could be:

```
varObject = @driver.find_element(:xpath,"//span[@ng-bind-html='$ctrl.app.publishedDate']")
```

Comment: Works like a champ!  I needed to change the //span to //*, but other than that it's working.  I'll have to try setting up the other objects on the page this way and see how it goes.

Comment: I needed to add a begin recover piece to my code.  I guess the "ng-bind-html" is not a static field.  Sometimes it changes to "ng-bind".